# Can I create a custom link in Flask to a specific item on the page?

Tags: javascript, python, flask, audio

I have a page in my Flask project with several links to audio files (mysite.com/soundpage/)These each have an "onclick" javascript trigger. When a user clicks the link, the audio file loads into the audio player and plays. I have controls="nodownload" set, so this is just streaming.

I am wondering if it is at all possible to make it so a user can use a direct URL to an audio file so the page will load up with the requested file selected and start playing, as opposed to going to the page and clicking. I understand some additional JS will be needed on page load to select and play the file.

But my main question is: Can Flask do this? I can't seem to find a clear answer anywhere.

For example: mysite.com/soundpage/song.mp3

The user uses that URL and the page loads with "song.mp3" loaded into the audio player.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Yep, it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is in fact possible, what you will have to do is add a new element to the page that plays when the page is loaded, in the case your url is mysite.com/soundpage/song.mp3 this way if the song in the url is actually in the build folder it will be immediately played:

```
<audio autoplay>
  <source src={window.location.href.split("/")[window.location.href.split("/").length - 1]} type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Keep in mind that this means sendig over to the client all the songs in the site, using ajax would be wiser

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

You could do this in flask, and just keep the `***.mp3` extension:

```
@app.route('/soundpage')
@app.route('/soundpage/<path:path>')
def soundpage(path=''):
    template_context = {
        'file_name': path
    }
    return render_template('my_template.html', **template_context )
```

then:

```
<audio autoplay>
    <source src="{{ url_for( 'static', filename=file_name) }}" type="audio/mp4">
</audio>
```

Not sure it would work in all browsers, as some prefs may try to download any mp3 file.  Try it.

**Update 2**

If you want to serve clickable links if they haven't yet selected a file, you can try:

```
{% if file_name == '' %}
    ..... serve some other html here
{% else %}
    <audio autoplay>
        <source src="{{ url_for( 'static', filename=file_name) }}" type="audio/mp4">
    </audio>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I actually have the files on my server in a static folder. Let's say I have "var/www/soundpage/static/song.mp3" and in my soundpage HTML I have "url_for{{ 'static', filename='song.mp3". Could I get your first example to work with something like "mysite.com/soundpage/song.mp3"?

Comment: Yes, but that will just play or download the MP3 in the browser, on its own page.  I think you want it to play within a web page with more content?  You could force a trailing slash to prevent the asking for a static file.  Let me test something.  BRB

Comment: Yes, I was able to parse it and get it working in Chrome.  Can't speak for other browsers

Comment: What if I have multiple mp3s on the page? Would they all require their own app route? I also want to be able to still have the user go to "mysite.com/soundpage" and let them click individually.

Comment: No, the <path:path> acts like a wildcard for all the urls.  See Update for serving a generic page with links.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. It wasn't 100% what I needed, but it was enough to point me in the right direction. For all intents and purposes, I got the code functioning. Unfortunately Chrome doesn't allow for autoplaying files on initial page load. What a rip off!